# Cakephp using this->set without array

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong here:

I have a controller with:

```
$this->set('sizes', array('4x4'=>'4x4','6x6'=>'6x6','8x8'=> '8x8'));
```

The view has the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('size');
```

A dropdown box is displayed with the array correctly.

In the same controller under the same function I have:

```
$this->set('states', 'this state');
```

The view has the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('state');
```

But the "state" text box does not have any info in it.
If I change the state line to:

```
$this->set('states', array('this state'));
```

A dropdown box will display with the single entry. I would like to have the textbox populate with the info instead of a dropdown box. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, have you tried setting the `type` of the form input?

```
$this->Form->input('state', array('type' => 'text'));
```

Probably the input isn't populated because it uses the singular "state" instead of "states". It has also always been my understanding that form fields are populated with data from the `$this->data/$this->request->data` array. Selects, checkboxes, etc. are a special case, because they have an options array, which in the case of your size input is populated with `$sizes`.

So let's say your form model is `Order` and you set `$this->request->data` in your `OrdersController`:

```
$this->request->data['Page']['state'] = 'this state';
```

If that doesn't work for you for some reason, you can always set the value of the input explicitly:

```
$this->Form->input('state', array('value' => $states));
```